# Questions about the Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

$$f(x)\sim \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n \cos{(\frac{2 n \pi x}{L})}+b_n \sin{(\frac{2 n \pi x}{L})}) \ \ \ \ \ (*)$$

The symbol $\sim$ has the following meaning:

We know that the right part of $(*)$ converges with the meaning of the induced norm  to an element of the space $E$. We don't know by now if the series at the right part converges pointwise to $f$.

What does the following part mean??
$$\text{ ...converges with the meaning of the induced norm  ... }$$

$$$$

Furthermore, the series at the right part is periodic with period $L$.

How do we know that the period is $L$??

Comment: Part b:  Replace $x$ with $x+L$, apply trigonometric identities, and discover that the value of the right hand side is unchanged under this replacement.

Comment: Do you know the theorems of convergence for Fourier series? There are several norms in which it can converges and not (depending on the assumptions). Look at any elementary Fourier analysis or PDE book, see, for instance Strauss book.

Comment: What is the space $E$? Does it have a norm?

Comment: What is $f(x+L)$? Can you simplify it?

Comment: $E$ is the space of the partially continuous functions.
$$$$
In $E$,there is the dot product: $$(\phi,\psi)=\int_{\frac{-L}{2}}^{\frac{L}{2}} \phi(x) \psi(x) dx$$

Answer (score 1):

The induced norm should reflect the special norm derived from the usual inner product on $L_2$.

The second part can be derived using the properties of sine and cosine functions.